# statusTxt, jqXHR not working in Iframe jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, jqxhr

I am trying to get the `responseTxt, statusTxt, jqXHR` output but it is not working in the iframe instead it only working in the load function. I have seen the related threads but it was not helpful.

I am trying after load iframe it will show an alert as `LOADED` as in my code but it not working.

Could you please help me to create this function how I get `responseTxt, statusTxt, jqXHR` response while iframe src change?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "li> a[target='iframeload']", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var designation = $(this).attr("href");
    if (!window.navigator.onLine) {
      alert("Net Lost");
      return false;
    } else {
      $("iframe#iframeID").attr("src", designation, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, jqXHR) {
        if (statusTxt == "success") {
          alert("LOADED");
        } else {
          if (statusTxt == "error") {
            alert("Error : " + jqXHR.status + " " + jqXHR.statusText);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `responseText`, `statusText` and `jqXHR` are arguments related to AJAX requests in jQuery. They are not available in a plain old HTML iframe element. What exactly are you trying to do? Aside from the issue, note that if the iframe `src` is on a third-party domain then you cannot access any data within the frame and the issue is entirely moot.

Comment: I am trying after iframe load OR at the time of Iframe load if any error comes it will show in the alert. so show we can understand what is the issue while loading the iframe